Are Next.js Streaming and Dynamic Imports the Same?
I'm working on a Next.js project and I'm a bit confused about the differences between streaming and dynamic imports.
I understand that streaming with server components allows the server to progressively send parts of the page to the client as soon as they are ready. This seems to improve the initial load time and user experience by delivering the HTML in chunks, even while some data might still be loading on the server.
On the other hand, dynamic imports using the next/dynamic function let me lazy load components on the client-side only when they are needed, which can reduce the initial JavaScript bundle size and improve performance.
My question is:
Are these two approaches achieving the same result in different ways?
What are the key differences between using streaming and dynamic imports in Next.js?
When should I choose one over the other?
Any clarification or examples of when to use each would be greatly appreciated!
What I Tried:
I've experimented with both streaming and dynamic imports in my Next.js project:

Streaming: I used server components with streaming to progressively send parts of my page to the client. This allowed the HTML to render as soon as the data was available, without waiting for the entire page to be ready. This approach seemed beneficial for server-side rendering and improved perceived load times.

Dynamic Imports: I used next/dynamic to lazy load some client-side components. This helped reduce the initial JavaScript bundle size and improved client-side performance by loading components only when they were needed, like on user interaction or specific route changes.


What I Expected:
I was expecting these two approaches to achieve similar performance benefits, but through different mechanisms. I thought both methods were geared towards improving loading times and user experience by reducing the amount of data sent at once.
My Confusion:
I'm not entirely sure if these two techniques serve the same purpose or if they should be used in specific scenarios. I’m hoping to understand their differences and when to use one over the other for optimal performance in a Next.js application.
